# Python 3 and Sklearn: Difficulty to use a NOT-sklearn model as a sklearn model

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation

The code below is working. I have just a routine to run a cross validation scheme using a linear model previous defined in sklearn. I do not have a problem with this. My problem is that: if I replace the code `model=linear_model.LinearRegression()` by the `model=RBF('multiquadric')` (please see line 14 and 15 in the `__main__`, it does not work anymore. So my problem is actually in the class RBF where I try to mimic a sklearn model.

If I replace the code described above, I get the following error:

```
  FitFailedWarning)
/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: All arrays must be equal length.

  FitFailedWarning)
```

1) Should I define a score function in the Class RBF?

2) How to do that? I am lost. Since I am inherit BaseEstimator and RegressorMixin, I expected that this was internally solved.

3) Is there something else missing?

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
np.random.seed(0)
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin



class RBF(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self,function):
        self.function=function
    def fit(self,x,y):
        self.rbf = Rbf(x, y,function=self.function)
    def predict(self,x):   
        return self.rbf(x)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Load Data
    targetName='HousePrice'
    data=datasets.load_boston()
    featuresNames=list(data.feature_names)
    featuresData=data.data
    targetData = data.target
    df=pd.DataFrame(featuresData,columns=featuresNames)
    df[targetName]=targetData
    independent_variable_list=featuresNames
    dependent_variable=targetName
    X=df[independent_variable_list].values
    y=np.squeeze(df[[dependent_variable]].values)    
    # Model Definition    
    model=linear_model.LinearRegression()
    #model=RBF('multiquadric')    
    # Cross validation routine
    number_splits=5
    score_list=['neg_mean_squared_error','neg_mean_absolute_error','r2']
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=number_splits,shuffle=True, random_state=0)
    scalar = StandardScaler()
    pipeline = Pipeline([('transformer', scalar), ('estimator', model)])
    results = model_selection.cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring=score_list,return_train_score=True)
    for score in score_list:
        print(score+':')
        print('Train: '+'Mean',np.mean(results['train_'+score]),'Standard Error',np.std(results['train_'+score]))
        print('Test: '+'Mean',np.mean(results['test_'+score]),'Standard Error',np.std(results['test_'+score]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html)

> *args : arrays
>
> x, y, z, …, d, where x, y, z, … are the coordinates of the nodes and d is the array of values at the nodes

So it takes variable length argument with the last argument being the value which is `y` in your case. Argument `k` is the `k`th coordinates of all the data point (same for all other argument `z, y, z, …`.

Following the documentation, your code should be

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
np.random.seed(0)
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin

class RBF(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self,function):
        self.function=function
    def fit(self,X,y):        
        self.rbf = Rbf(*X.T, y,function=self.function)

    def predict(self,X):   
        return self.rbf(*X.T)


# Load Data
data=datasets.load_boston()

X = data.data
y = data.target


number_splits=5
score_list=['neg_mean_squared_error','neg_mean_absolute_error','r2']

kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=number_splits,shuffle=True, random_state=0)
scalar = StandardScaler()

model = RBF(function='multiquadric')

pipeline = Pipeline([('transformer', scalar), ('estimator', model)])

results = model_selection.cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring=score_list,return_train_score=True)

for score in score_list:
        print(score+':')
        print('Train: '+'Mean',np.mean(results['train_'+score]),'Standard Error',np.std(results['train_'+score]))
        print('Test: '+'Mean',np.mean(results['test_'+score]),'Standard Error',np.std(results['test_'+score]))
```

### Output

```
neg_mean_squared_error:
Train: Mean -1.552450953914355e-20 Standard Error 7.932530906290208e-21
Test: Mean -23.007377210596463 Standard Error 4.254629143836107
neg_mean_absolute_error:
Train: Mean -9.398502208736061e-11 Standard Error 2.4673749061941226e-11
Test: Mean -3.1319779583728673 Standard Error 0.2162343985534446
r2:
Train: Mean 1.0 Standard Error 0.0
Test: Mean 0.7144217179633185 Standard Error 0.08526294242760363
```

**Why `*X.T`** : As we saw, each argument correspond to an axis of all the data points, so we transpose them and then use `*` operator to expand and pass each of the sub array as an argument to the variable length function.

Looks like the latest implementation has a `mode` parameter where we can pass the `N-D` array directly.